# Zend DB Select version of a simple Mysql Left Join

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select

I have a simple Left query on mysql

```
SELECT sp. * , p.name, p.date_created
FROM subpages sp
LEFT JOIN pages p ON p.id = sp.page_id
```

I dont know how to execuite this query from zend framework.

I have a Mapper Page, which access a DbTable page which is extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. I read some articles so i suppose statement should look something like this from the mapper

```
$select = $this -> DbTable() -> select();
$select -> joinleft(..... This is what I dont know how to write....);
$results = $this -> DbTable() -> fetchAll($select);
if($results) { return $result; }
```

In the article, `$select -> from()` were used, that where my mind is stuck , why do we need to write `$select -> from("subpages")` when It will already be defined in the DbTable page.

How to write the join statement properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the select with multiple tables, you need to get it from the **table adapter**, which is a `Zend_Db` object (and you'll need to specify your table in the `from()` method).

So, you would need something like the following:

```
$select = $this->DbTable()->getAdapter()->select();
$select->from(array("mi" => "tableName"));
$select->joinLeft(array("p" => "pages"), "p.id = mi.page_id");
(etc)
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Ok, I can use this to go my thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the query you posted , you can use the following

```
 (You have not mentioned table name for ailas 'mi' so I have taken it as 'your_table_name' )

$select = $this -> DbTable() -> select()->from(array("your_table_name" => 'mi');
$select -> joinleft(array("pages" => 'p'),"p.id = mi.page_id");
$results = $this -> DbTable() -> fetchAll($select);
if($results) { return $result; }

Hope it will work for you mrN.
```

Comment: mi was a mistake, it is sp. How to define indiviudal fields p.name and p.date_created

Comment: and an errors occurs `Zend_Db_Table_Select_Exception: Select query cannot join with another table`